# codeigniter 3 subfolder showing page not found for root directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

i am having this weird problem with codeigniter 3.
I've just started developing for a large app in which I have created sub folders within the controllers directory. eg:
applications

```
> -->controllers
> ---->account
> ------>Home.php
> ------>Users.php
> ---->public
> ------>Home.php
> ------>Users.php
```

my routes:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

here is what does NOT work:

- http://localhost/
- I was expecting this to load http://localhost/public and defaulting to the home controller within public
- instead this is loading a page not found for me
- ultimately, if the URI is empty, i would like
  'public' be considered as default.

here is what works:

- http://localhost/account   /* loads account/home controller index */
- http://localhost/account/users /*loads account/users index function
  */
- http://localhost/public    /* loads public/home controller index */
- http://localhost/public/users  /*loads public/users index function */

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try with Home.php and not home.php

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. it is already named as 'Home.php'

Comment: Have you setup routes `$route['users'] = 'public/users';` http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: Yes... the issue is still with root... http://localhost is giving me a page not found... http://localhost should be loading public/home... I have tried $route[''] = 'public/home'; and it did not help.

Comment: On codeigniter 3 only on default controller in route does not allow sub folders

Comment: I see, so recommendation is to move the default controller back to the controller root folder?

Comment: Yes like application > controllers > Home.php for public all other routes in codeigniter bar the default one your allowed subfolders but if you use HMVC it works